# How to access Android from browser

Tags: java, javascript, android, sockets

I have seen a few applications recently called lazyview and airdroid on Android, that connect via wireless to any browser, using local ip address and port. The things they access can be applications, battery view, basically most settings including video photos etc, not just the file structures. Does anyone know how this is done, or if there is any open source code that can do this.

Comment: You need some kind of java HTTP server. There is a lot of source examples around that you can take as a starting point. Either Android-specific or just java.

Comment: Thanks for that. Puts me in right direction. Do you know of any good open source ones off hand. I am just looking at Ijetty that looks quite promising.

Comment: I just experimented a bit, nothing serious, so could not advise anything specific. I used [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/Webserver/WebServercode.html) WebServer implementation and my application was very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a webserver in your application. For example: [Tiny Java Webserver](http://tjws.sourceforge.net/), [i-jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/)